# transform my rdf file to a named graph file

Tags: java, jena, semantic-web, blazegraph, named-graphs

For a project I have to use Apache Jena as an API and Blazegraph as a triple store, I am trying to program a code that allows me to transform my dataset (N-Triples File) to a file that contains the NamedGraph of each statement.

```
String APIUrl = "http://localhost:9999/bigdata/namespace/drugbank/sparql";
String req = "select * WHERE {?x ?y ?z}";

RDFConnection conn = RDFConnectionFactory.connect(APIUrl);
FileManager.get().addLocatorClassLoader(Main.class.getClassLoader());
Model model = FileManager.get().loadModel("drugbank.nt",null,"NTRIPLES");
conn.load(model);

Query query = QueryFactory.create(req);
QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query,model);
    try {
        ResultSet rs = qexec.execSelect();

        Model m1 = RDFOutput.encodeAsModel(rs);
        StmtIterator iter = m1.listStatements();

        int i=0;
        final Model mStat = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            i++;
            Statement stmt      = iter.nextStatement() ;
            // code for named Graph
        }
   }catch(Exception){

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can load the model directly to a remote named graph:

`conn.load(model);` loads the default graph.

`conn.load(graphName, model);` loads a named graph.