# Connect Jena 2.6.2 with BlazeGraph

Tags: java, dataset, jena, blazegraph

Hy everyone,

For a project I have to use Apache Jena 2.6.2 as an API and Blazegraph as a triple store, So i want to use `RDFConnection conn = RDFConnectionFactory.connect`for connecting Jena with blazegraph but the class RDFConnection is not resolved in jena 2.6.2.

I need your help to find another method or another class to connect jena with blazegraph.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: There is no Apache Jena 2.6.2. The earliest Apache release was 2.7.0 in 2011.  2.6.2 is very old and a lot has changed since then. Better to start with Apache Jena 3.8.0.

Comment: See question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52060818/.